# Google App maker multiple files drive upload

Tags: google-app-maker

We are going to use drive picker as attachement field, so whenever an user uploads a file or multiples files to drive we have to get the links of the files and show it to the user in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code sample with following assumptions:

- you have Master and Attachment models with One-to-Many relation
- datasource of the current page is set to record from the Master model
- datasource is in Auto Save mode

```js
// onDocumentSelect Drive Picker's event handler
var create = widget.root.datasource.relations.Attachments.modes.create;

result.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
  create.item.Url = doc.url;
  create.createItem();
});
```

This code will make N requests to the server, where N is number of attachments. You can use `google.script.run` to make a single call and handle creating new attachment records and relations on server, but then you'll need manually reload relation to show changes to user.

Comment: 2nd point is mentioned as datasource should be set to record from the master model, But I can't find the created relations in datsource

Comment: What do you mean? Are you receiving `undefined` exception or you just don't see relation in editor's autocomplete?

Comment: Yeah i can see relation in autocomplete but need to know steps to configure the one to many relations and how to store and retrieve from the model to end user

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/relations, https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#prefetch