# App maker: Return from the Drive Picker multiple selected files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-app-maker

I made a drive picker for attaching files in a description of a ticket.
I want to be able to attach more than one file so I made in the features of the Drive Picker "MULTISELECT_ENABLED",Now I can select more than one item from my drive but it return one item only.
I want to know how to return the array of the selected items?
[image: MULTISELECT_ENABLED feature]
[image]

Also when I searched for that, I found that uploading a new item to your drive using drive picker would cause a problem if another user wants to see this item, he will not be able due to sharing options.
I want to know how to be able to attach more than an item in the description of a ticket whether by a drive picker or not.

Update1:

I created a new table for the attachments instead of putting its fields in Tickets table and made a relation One to Many.
I modified the code in the proposed answer on Document select:

```
// onDocumentSelect Drive Picker's event handler
var create = widget.root.datasource.relations.Tickets_Attachments.modes.create;
var tickets = app.datasources.Tickets;
var attachments = app.datasources.Tickets_Attachments;
result.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
  create.item.Attachment_name = doc.url;
  attachments.saveChanges();
  create.createItem();
});
tickets.saveChanges();
```

But this error appeared:
"Cannot create new record in relation datasource unless parent record exists."
So changed the code to the above one and  saved the changes after creating an attachment item but nothing changed.
[image: One to Many relationship]
[image: Attachments_Tickets Table inside create Ticket]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App maker multiple files drive upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999270/google-app-maker-multiple-files-drive-upload)

Comment: The proposed copied answer should do what you want. You need to use the onDocumentSelect event to do something with those docs, looks like you are just saving your datasource changes and not actually handling the documents that were selected with the picker.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa
Please check my edited question

Comment: @Jescanellas Please check my edited question.

Comment: I should have a solution for you but can’t check till tomorrow some time. However, your error is happening because you can’t create a related item to a record that is in create mode itself. So the work around is to assign the attachments to a page stored datasource and on the submit button click first create the ticket record and upon successful completion then create the attachments which are located in a temporary datasource. I should be able to provide more detail later.